# Relay: Query breaking with no sign of what is wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relay, react-relay

I've began to learn graphql (adding relay here), so i followed up the steps to have relay running, i created my first query:

```
function fetchQuery(operation, variables) {
  return fetch("http://localhost:3000/graphql", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: operation.text,
      variables
    })
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}

const modernEnvironment = new Environment({
  network: Network.create(fetchQuery),
  store: new Store(new RecordSource())
});

class ClientList extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        envieronment={modernEnvironment}
        query={graphql`
          query ClientListQuery {
            clients {
              name
              cnpj
              ie
            }
          }
        `}
        variables={{}}
        render={({ error, props }) => {
          console.log("props", props);
          return <h1>hi</h1>;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

But it fails, with the following error on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unstable_internal' of
>   undefined
>       at fetchQueryAndComputeStateFromProps (ReactRelayQueryRenderer.js:214)
>       at new ReactRelayQueryRenderer (ReactRelayQueryRenderer.js:74)
>       at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:11447)
>       at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13144)
>       at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13824)
>       at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15863)
>       at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15902)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: Not really, because i don't want to detect anything inside relay, somehow it threw an error on relay, and it has no signs of what has throw it. I cannot debug relay source-code, so it is not in my realm. And also, that does not answer this question.